# Programmatically get host's ip from within Docker container with Python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, networking

I'm aware that you can get a host's ip programatically with Python doing something like:

```py
from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname

ip = gethostbyname(gethostname())
print(ip)
```

but, as expected, when running the code mentioned above from a container (just ftr, with *user namespaces* enabled) the output is **172.17.0.2**.

How can I programmatically get the host's ip from within the container?

**Note**: I'm working in a Linux environment.

Comment: A container can't normally see the host's IP addresses (plural); this is doubly true if you're running inside a VM-based Docker environment like Docker Desktop.  [Using the host ip in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061026/using-the-host-ip-in-docker-compose) suggests an approach based on finding an appropriate IP address on the host and injecting it into the container as an environment variable; does that work for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze I think the option of passing the IP address as an environment variable is the only one left. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This works on my mac

```
ip = gethostbyname('docker.for.mac.localhost')
```

Comment: sorry, I have updated the questions. I need it for Linux systems. Btw, I think nowadays is `host.docker.internal`.